# Async/Await - Python vs Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand asynchronous programming, namely async/await. My current understanding is that using the await keyword will wait for a promise to resolve before continuing on. With this in mind, I made two scripts in Python and Javascript.

Python:

```
import asyncio


async def stall(func, s):
    await asyncio.sleep(s)
    func()

async def hello():
    def stop():
        print("hello() stop")
    print("hello() start")
    await stall(stop, 5)

async def main():
    def stop():
        print("main() stop")
    print("main() start")
    await asyncio.create_task(hello())
    await asyncio.create_task(stall(stop, 3))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Javascript:

```
function stall(func, ms) {
    return new Promise(() => {
        setTimeout(func, ms)
    })
}

async function hello() {
    console.log("hello() start")
    await stall(() => {console.log("hello() stop")}, 5000)
}

async function main() {
    console.log("main() start")
    await hello()
    await stall(() => {console.log("main() stop")}, 3000)
}

main()
```

When writing the scripts, I thought they would do the same thing. However, the output is different.

Python:

```
main() start
hello() start
hello() stop
main() stop
```

Javascript:

```
main() start
hello() start
hello() stop
```

Using Powershell, I typed this command:

```
Measure-Command { node .\async_await.js | out-default }
```

and this is the output:

```
main() start
hello() start
hello() stop


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 5
Milliseconds      : 121
Ticks             : 51210409
TotalDays         : 5.9271306712963E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00142251136111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.0853506816666667
TotalSeconds      : 5.1210409
TotalMilliseconds : 5121.0409
```

Shouldn't it take a total of 8 second? Am I correct in saying that Javascript will wait for hello() but not stall() in the main method? If so, why doesn't Javascript wait for stall() to finish? If not, what is Javascript doing when awaiting the two functions?

Sorry if the answer is obvious or if I made some silly mistake.

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't know anything about async coding.  It is very, very different from `asyncio.sleep`.  Thus, it returns immediately, so your `stall` doesn't really stall.  The program ends before the second timeout expires.

Answer (score 1):

The promise you're returning from `stall` never settles (it is never fulfilled or rejected) which ends up suspending your `hello()` function indefinitely at its first `await`. To fulfil a promise that you create using [`new Promise()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise), you need to call `resolve()` within its [executor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters) function. You can do this by updating the executor to use the `resolveFunc` it gets passed and then call that when the `setTimeout()` callback is called:

```js
function stall(func, ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { // use the resolveFunc
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(); // resolve the promise
      func();
    }, ms);
  });
}

async function hello() {
  console.log("hello() start");
  await stall(() => {console.log("hello() stop")}, 5000);
}

async function main() {
  console.log("main() start");
  await hello();
  await stall(() => {console.log("main() stop")}, 3000);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused, if you could provide some clarification. hello() gets suspended indefinitely, but stops waiting after 5 seconds? What's the difference between suspending hello() indefinitely and suspending main() indefinitely? If I made stall() async instead of explicitly returning a new Promise, how would I resolve the Promise correctly?

Comment: @asdf When a function hits an `await` the function's execution is "paused" (ie: suspended), so its waiting/suspended until the promise it's waiting on settles. It doesn't stop waiting after 5s. After 5s, all that happens is your `setTimeout` callback is executed and the code within that runs, but the promise continues to be in a pending state (as nothing resolved it and no errors occurred).

Comment: If `hello()` is suspended and stuck because the promise it's waiting on never settles, then the promise that `hello()` implicitly returns will also never settle, and so `main()` will be suspended at `await hello()`

Comment: Making `stall()` an `async` function won't really help or change much. If `setTimeout()` natively returned a promise then you'd be able to change it's implementation such that you `await` the `setTimeout()` call. But native JS doesn't have a "delay" or "wait" method that natively returns a promise, so you need to explicitly create your promise using `new Promise()` such that you can call `resolve()` once it executes its callback (as shown in the answer), otherwise, if you create an `async` promise that doesn't use `await` inside of it

Comment: all it will do is return a promise that resolves immediately  (equivalent to doing `function stall() { /* ... your setTimeout code ... */ return Promise.resolve()}`, here `Promise.resolve()` just returns a Promise that resolves immediately, but that isn't really useful to the calling code of `stall()` as it doesn't provide any information about whether `stall()` has finished its asynchronous operation, and your `setTimeout()` would continue to run and wouldn't be linked to the resolution of the promise that had been returned.